# in html theme integration in angular 16 project , when we partially distributed in component then no CSS and javascript code applied

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular, angular16

when we distributed html block of code in to different component then no CSS and javascript code applied in different component
so what to do in differnt component for applying css and javascript

in angular 16 project , html theme code put in index.html then page is working fine but we divide in component no CSS and javascript applied

code shown as

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testproject</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png" />
  
  <!-- Plugins CSS -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/plugins.css">
  
  <!-- Bootstap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <!-- Main Style CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css">



</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

        <!-- Including Jquery -->
        <script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/vendor/modernizr-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/vendor/wow.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Including Javascript -->
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/lazysizes.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <!--For Newsletter Popup-->
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('.closepopup').on('click', function () {
                    jQuery('#popup-container').fadeOut();
                    jQuery('#modalOverly').fadeOut();
                });

                var visits = jQuery.cookie('visits') || 0;
                visits++;
                jQuery.cookie('visits', visits, { expires: 1, path: '/' });
                console.debug(jQuery.cookie('visits'));
                if (jQuery.cookie('visits') > 1) {
                    jQuery('#modalOverly').hide();
                    jQuery('#popup-container').hide();
                } else {
                    var pageHeight = jQuery(document).height();
                    jQuery('<div id="modalOverly"></div>').insertBefore('body');
                    jQuery('#modalOverly').css("height", pageHeight);
                    jQuery('#popup-container').show();
                }
                if (jQuery.cookie('noShowWelcome')) { jQuery('#popup-container').hide(); jQuery('#active-popup').hide(); }
            });

            jQuery(document).mouseup(function (e) {
                var container = jQuery('#popup-container');
                if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    container.fadeOut();
                    jQuery('#modalOverly').fadeIn(200);
                    jQuery('#modalOverly').hide();
                }
            });
        </script>
        <!--End For Newsletter Popup-->

</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html page
`<app-home></app-home>`

home.component.html

```
    <div class="pageWrapper">
        <!--Search Form top header-->
            <app-top-header></app-top-header>
            <!--Search Form top header-->
        <!--End Top Header-->

        <!--Header-->

            <app-header></app-header>

        <!--End Header-->


      
        <!--Body Content-->
        <div id="page-content">
            <!--Home slider-->
 

            <!--Featured Product-->
          
        </div>
        <!--End Body Content-->

        <!--Footer-->
      
        <app-footer></app-footer>
        <!--End Footer-->
  

    

        <!-- Newsletter Popup -->
       <app-news-alert></app-news-alert>
        <!-- End Newsletter Popup -->

    </div>
```

how to divide html theme into different component and how to code to all applied in CSS and javascript